# Display a Progress Bar in Angular 5 for each Request Response time

Tags: npm, angular5, spinner

In my application that i am developing in Angular 5, once the request and response hits the API and get backs the data I need a process bar to be displayed in tracking the request response time in a form of progress bar. I'm using ngx-spinner where I statically give a certain period of time say 5 seconds. Where I have to load the page based on the response time.

```
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

setTimeout(() => {
        this.getusers();
    this.spinner.hide();      
        }, 5000);
```